# How to capture chronological changes to an array in SQL?

Tags: php, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

I have a simple, location based, key-value array (PHP), which changes throughout the day. I intend to capture variation in this array.

I can calculate the difference between previous array and current array values. I could, then  save them in SQL DB as:

Location, Date, Key, NewValue

How will the schema look like for this. My newbie attempt is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `Variations` (
  `Location` TEXT(128),
  `Date` DATETIME,
  `Key` TEXT(64),
  `Value` TEXT(256),
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
);
```

How would I know all the (latest) key value pairs at a given date ?
Looking for guidance on SQL query for data retrieval.

Comment: An auto_increment text field? Does that actually work?

Comment: @MarkBaker Updated to reflect ID

Comment: What's the query you've tried? Did you try adding WHERE clause such as *date('Date') = 'YYYY-MM-DD'*?

Comment: @ydoow I am trying to find appropriate 'where' clause to get latest value of every key on or before YYYYMMDD. If it looks compute intensive, I may have to change, how I am storing data. I am trying to avoid storing data ( or diff ) as a serialized hash for every single date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [autoincrementing ID](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) must be of type INTEGER, not INT, and AUTOINCREMENT (not AUTO_INCREMENT) has a meaning different from what you think it has.

To get the latest values for a date, you need rows for which no other row with a later date exists:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Variations
WHERE date(Date) <= 'xxxx-xx-xx'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Variations AS V2
                  WHERE V2.Location = Variations.Location
                    AND V2.Key = Variations.Key
                    AND V2.Date <= 'xxxx-xx-xx'
                    AND V2.Date > Variations.Date)
```

Comment: I was concerned about all keys for a given location being updated at different times. When I say, show the record based on YYYYMMDD, I wanted to the see the latest of every key value for the given location. Latest values of different keys could go from being on same day to as far back as few years. I will try this out in the evening and will revert back. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I think, this or a slight variation will work for me. I will post a comment at that time. Accepting this as an answer.